# Is there a way to check for the PyType of Python AST objects from C code?

Tags: python, c, abstract-syntax-tree

I am attempting to write a Python C extension that performs work on a Python AST which is passed from Python code.  However, I'm having some trouble checking the PyType of the passed object.

I have the following method, registered as `METH_O`, compiled into a Python module:

```
#include <Python.h>
// Python-ast.h defines PyAST_Check
#include <Python-ast.h>

static PyObject * python_is_ast(PyObject *Py_UNUSED(self), PyObject *obj) {
    if (PyAST_Check(obj)) Py_RETURN_TRUE;
    else Py_RETURN_FALSE;
}
```

If I try to import this code using Python 3.9.6, I get the error

> ImportError: /home/user/path/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/_module.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyAST_Check

I would think that PyAST_Check would need to be available in the interpreter, but apparently it isn't exported.  Is there a way to check for the PyType of Python AST objects from C code?

Comment: `PyObject_IsInstance`, I suppose. Of course, you'll need the AST base class; I don't know offhand how to get that. AIUI, the PyAST_Check interface is undocumented and not intended to be used in external code; in v3.9, it was removed from the limited API, and in v3.10 the Python-ast.h header has been removed.

Comment: @rici Where can I find the PyTypeObjects for the AST classes?  I have looked around and I haven't been able to find them.

Comment: It's `ast.AST` if there's nothing more specific.

Comment: @rici sorry to be a little slow, but I'm not sure what that PyTypeObject is called in the C API.  I understand the Python superclass is ast.AST.  Can you tell me what the PyType is called and in what header file I can find it?

Comment: No, I can't, sorry. I don't really know that much about the C API. But I do know that you can use the C API to do things like look up a module by name and get an object by name from a module.